# Force users to complete first name and last name in profile WordPress registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system

I have a question about WordPress functions.
I have written this code for our users to have a meta data after registration :

```
<?php
    add_action( 'user_register', 'add_registered_user_cap', 10, 1 );
    function add_registered_user_cap( $user_id ) {
   $hasfname = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
    $haslname = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', true);
    if($hasfname!=‘’ && $haslname!=‘’){
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'isverified', 1);
    } else{
   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'isverified', 0);
    }
}
?>
```

After that I want to redirect all users to edit profile page to complete it until they are fully completed.
So,I have this code:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo(); // wordpress global variable to fetch logged in user info
    $userID = $current_user->ID; // logged in user's ID
    $hasfname = get_user_meta($userID, 'first_name', true);
    $haslname = get_user_meta($userID, 'last_name', true);
    $isverified = get_user_meta($userID, 'isverified', true); // stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'test'.
    if( ($hasfname != '') && ($haslname != '') ){
            update_user_meta( $userID, 'isverified', 1);
    }
    if( ($isverified == 0) && ( (home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) != wc_customer_edit_account_url()) ) ){
        wp_redirect( wc_customer_edit_account_url() ); exit;
    }
}
?>
```

But when a guest want to complete his/her order on checkout page and pay for it, it almost redirect them though they will verify automatically because they have entered their first name and last name on billing information page. Anybody has a condition to prevent this redirection and let user to pay for order ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Woocommerce fill the user meta billing_first_name in the checkout page and not first_name.

I think the best solution it's control if the user_meta billing_first_name.

Anothe point is that Woocommerce fill this user_meta in the hook user_register. So i think your verify process it should be disabled in checkout.